# How to get the Subscribed Message in mqtt using MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mqtt

I tried mqtt publish and subscribe code in mvc,

i can able to publish message using the following code.

```
string MQTT_BROKER_ADDRESS = "212.72.74.21";
MqttClient client = new MqttClient(MQTT_BROKER_ADDRESS);
string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
client.Connect(clientId);
string strValue = "Message to be Send";
client.Publish("Topic", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strValue));
```

message gets published.

but when coming to subcribe a message i cant get it.

i used the following code.

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient("212.72.74.21");


client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
client.Connect(clientId);
client.Subscribe(new string[] { "Message1" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
```

subscribed message have to be handled in this following method.

```
static  void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
    //Handle Message recieved        
}
```

But My Problem is that program is not going inside the subscribe function.

How can i resolve it?

Kindly give some ideas to rectify my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a different topic for subscribing than the one you are publishing to. Make sure both topics are identical.

Change the following line to:

```
client.Publish("myTopic", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strValue));
```

And the following line to:

```
client.Subscribe(new string[] { "myTopic" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
```

In your delegate, print out some useful information to inform you that a message was received, for example:

```
static void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message received.");        
}
```